# JaxRsClient (OkHttpClient) is much slower than Feign (HttpURLConnection) or cURL

Tags: java, curl, networking, https

I have a REST endpoint that basically just uploads a file from the machine making the call to one of our cloud VMs.

When, from the client VM, I make the call with `cURL`, it takes ~10s to upload a 100 megabyte file.

When, from the client VM, I make the call with a [jaxrs client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.palantir.conjure.java.runtime/conjure-java-jaxrs-client/4.43.0), it takes ~2m50s to upload a 100 megabyte file.

Client code. I've played with creating a custom SSLSocketFactory, which allows me to turn knobs on SocketOptions, but that isn't in the snippet below.

```
        SslConfiguration sslConfig = SslConfiguration.of(Paths.get(trustStorePath));
        ClientConfiguration config = ClientConfigurations.of(
                ImmutableList.of(<uri>),
                SslSocketFactories.createSslSocketFactory(sslConfig),
                SslSocketFactories.createTrustManagers(sslConfig));

        MyService service = JaxRsClient.create(
                MyService.class,
                UserAgent.of(UserAgent.Agent.of("my-user-agent", "1.0.0")),
                new HostMetricsRegistry(),
                config);

       service.fooBar(...);
```

Host Endpoint (abstract definition)

```
    @POST
    @Path("path/foo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    void fooBar(
            @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) AuthHeader authHeader,
            InputStream fileData);
```

My question(s) is this: What might cause such a huge disparity in the network throughput? Are there any dials I can turn on the SocketOptions on the Java side that might help resolve this issue?

Any and all context/help would be appreciated!

Relevant Details:

- jre11.0.6
- TLSv1.2 (tried with both CBC and GCM cipher suites, no change for either)
- I've tinkered with TCP_NODELAY, SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF (via the SSLSocketFactory). TCP_NODELAY yielded ~10% perf improvement, while changing the SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF didn't affect anything.

### UPDATE 1

I switched to using a vanilla Feign client (HttpsURLConnection, under the hood):

```
        MyService service = Feign.builder()
                .client(new Client.Default(new KeepAliveSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()), null))
                .contract(new JAXRSContract())
                .encoder(
                        new InputStreamDelegateEncoder(
                                new TextDelegateEncoder(
                                        new CborDelegateEncoder(
                                                new ObjectMapper(),
                                                new ConjureFeignJacksonEncoder(objectMapper)))))
                .target(MyService.class, <url>);
```

and set the following block at the front of the class:

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
}
```

These two changes together (both the Feign client AND the Conscrypt provider) made the java call perform comparably to the `cURL`. However, if I add the Conscrypt provider to the original JaxRsClient, it's still slow. And the vanilla Feign client without the Conscrypt provider is also still slow.

It might also be worth noting, I've tried both GCM and CBC cipher suites, and they don't affect the perf at all (regardless of which client, or Conscrypt provider being set).

### UPDATE 2

So I've updated the JRE to 11.0.6, and with that change I no longer need to enable Conscrypt in order for  the Feign request to be fast. I've captured a JFR of the feign request (fast), and the JaxRsClient request (slow).

This is the Socket I/O on the Feign (HttpURLConnection under the hood) request
[image: This is the socket I/O on the Feign (HttpURLConnection) request]

This is the Socket I/O on the JaxRsClient (OkHttpClient under the hood) request
[image: This is the socket I/O on the JaxRsClient (OkHttpClient) request]

These were viewed using Java Mission Control. What's interesting is that the slow request is just a ton of reads on the socket (~200), and the fast request is 3 reads and 15 writes. Just as a sanity check, I also switched between CBC and GCM cipher suites on both of these requests, with no real difference between the two.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you use for the jaxrs client. In general network speed that varies by application is usually a buffer/packetization problem. The larger the buffer is and the larger the sent data packets are the faster the transfer speed is. For example once I made a mistake and sent data single byte wise to a server - hence each byte was wrapped in an protocol adding 10-100 bytes...

Comment: The client code is pretty standard, I added it above (pretty much straight out of the docs from the jaxrsclient link I provided. I also added some more details about the environment/protocols I'm using.

Comment: What is the method signature for returning the data in `MyService`? Do you use `StreamingOutput`?

Comment: @Robert, the file is passed as an `InputStream` to the method in `MyService`. In the case of feign client + Conscrypt provider (see UPDATE 1), varying the types of `InputStream` don't noticeably affect perf at all. I've also loaded a 100mb "file" in memory (not reading from disk), and that didn't affect perf either.

Comment: Please post the actual client code. Claiming it is 'pretty standard' is not good enough.

Comment: @user207421 the `MyService` class I cannot share. I'm using the exact same configuration I defined in the snippet above to create my JaxRsClient. So, for all intents and purposes, that is the actual client code. (assume a valid truststorePath and url)

Comment: @user207421 I've added the abstract method signature for the endpoint being consumed. I've also added the way I construct the Feign client (the way I construct the JaxRsClient is already there). Let me know if I can provide anything else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm a little unsatisfied that I don't have more depth to this answer, but here it is.

The JaxRsClient was negotiating HTTP/2. I'm not sure what was going on under the hood, but if GCM ciphers weren't enabled, the only allowed protocol should've been HTTP1.1. Here's the PR that corrected the issue:

https://github.com/palantir/conjure-java-runtime/commit/e52efdc1f66a52c3ee9112ecaae7bb40ac799224

The JaxRsClient, after that change, wouldn't negotiate HTTP/2 if GCM ciphers were NOT enabled. On HTTP/1.1, it matched `cURL` and `Feign` for speed.